# Checking Angular route params ID failing, for null or undefined string

Tags: angular, typescript, exception

Let's say I go to a component whose URL is **localhost:4200/myComponent/id**. Whatever the ID is, it appears as a string in the component view.

This code takes the ID parameter from the previous component ([routerLink]="['/myComponent', id]"), and extracts the value for internal usage this way:

**myComponent.ts**

```
getURLId(): void {

    this.route.params
      .map(
        params => params['id'])
          .subscribe(
            ((id) => this.assignID(id)),
            err => {
              this.successData = false;
              this.errorMessage = err
            });

  }
```

This value of "id" is compared to NULL and UNDEFINED, with the goal handling errors myself. When accessing **localhost:4200/mycomponent/** intentionally leaving ID blank, my code should know that route.params has an undefined value for "id" and stop:

```
assignID(id: string): void {

    // THIS COMPARISON IS NOT CATCHING THE SCENARIO MENTIONED ABOVE
    if(id === null || id === undefined) {

      // DECLARE ERROR AND RAISE FLAG

    } else {

      // DO THINGS WITH "id" HERE...

    }
  }
```

The problem is that **localhost:4200/mycomponent/** does not yield true for the comparison (id === null or undefined).

Console.log of the "id" value outputs *undefined* as it should.

What gives?

Comment: how is routing looks like? I think with empty id Angular route should not even select this route with id.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have configure route properly

```
{ path: 'mycomponent/:id', component: MyComponent },
```

To get route params we don't need to map it. We can directly subscribe it.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.assignID(params['id']);
});
```